# Journals similar to "Positivity"?

Tags: reference-request, journals

Speaks of my own ignorance, but only a few days ago (thanks to MO), I discovered the journal called [Positivity](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/journal/11117)

I really liked many of the articles in that journal, and wanted to know if the better informed MO folks could provide me a list of other journals that publish work on similar topics (e.g., for positive operators, LAA is also a great source).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators and Matrices, Journal of Operator Theory